# ampersand in mailto php string is breaking rest of string

Tags: php, mailto

I am creating dynamic `mailto` links using the below code.

```
<?php echo urlencode(str_replace(" ", "%20",  the_title() )); ?>
```

The problem is that when the title contains an `ampersand`, it breaks the `mailto` string with spaces.

```
the_title();
```

Outputs: **Menu Salmon Crab & Tuna**

Even though I am finding and replacing the spaces, the spaces seem to appear breaking the string.  When I look in the source, this is what I get.

```
mailto:?Subject=Menu%20Salmon%20Crab &#038; Tuna
```

The same code works for **Menu Salmon Crab**

Can anyone help me understand why. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you double URL-encoding?  No need for your `str_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any problem with having spaces in the `mailto`, try:

```
<?php
    echo urlencode('my string with & sign');
?>
```